# Using laravel Groupby to iterate through collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to iterate through a collection and store a record per groupby('type'). At the moment it store all individual records line by line, yet the expected behaviour I need is to store group totals.

dd() returns this. So I want all the appointments hours for a group to SUM and then store the group, .i.e Test = 5 hours. Test2 = 3 hours.

```
Collection {#471 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Test" => Collection {#460 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Appointment {#463 ▶}
        1 => Appointment {#464 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "Test2" => Collection {#450 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Appointment {#465 ▶}
        1 => Appointment {#466 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the controller code.

```
   foreach($appointments as $appointment)
{   
  $duration = [];                           
  $aType = $appointments->groupBy('type');  

  foreach($aType as $type)
  {                                         
    $duration[]         = $date1->diffInMinutes($date2);          
  }

$totalhours             = array_sum($duration); //sum the hours

$Item             = new AppItem;                                
$Item->type           = $aType->type;      
$Item->total_hours = $totalhours;
$Item->save();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understand your question here, but I'm not sure you need to group by since the item's are already sorted by "group", i.e. Test, Test2, etc. Would this work:

```
$collection->each(function($group, $appointments) {
    return [$group => collect($appointments)->sum(function ($appointment) {
        return $appointment->date1->diffInMinutes($appointment->date2);
    });
});
```

That should return something like

```
['Test' => 5, 'Test2' => 8]
```

If this isn't correct can you give more sample data and an example of what a good result would look like?

Answer (score 0):

This ended being the working solution. There is  probably a neater way. In the do stuff sections, you then work with the object returned from previous foreach.

```
    $appointments = Appointment::find($id)
                    ->get();

$aType = $appointments->groupBy('type');
        $invoice_total = [];
    foreach($aType as $key => $value)
        {   
            $duration = []; 
            foreach($value as $a)
            {

                $date1  = Carbon::parse($a->starts_at);     
                $date2  =  Carbon::parse($a->ends_at);                                      
                $duration[] = $date1->diffInMinutes($date2)/60; //divide by 60 to return hours  

        } 

    $Item             = new AppItem;                                
    $Item->type           = $aType->type;      
    $Item->total_hours = $totalhours;
    $Item->save();    
}

//other stuff
}
```